# How do I properly return money double variable in Java

Tags: java, variables, currency

I'm currently working on an assignment for school where I need to write a program that it needs to return your change in this mode

Input:
purchaseAmount:  $12.45
givenAmount:    $15.00

Output: 
Change: $2.55
2 one dollar bills
2 quarters
1 nickel

But, if I work with this case scenario it works fine. Now, If I want this scenario to work this what I get

Input:
purchaseAmount:  $19.51
givenAmount:    $50.01

Output:

Twenty dollar bill 1
Ten dollar bill: 1
Quarters: 1
Dimes: 2
Pennies: 4

Which is incorrect since I'm returning to the costumer 30.49 instead of 30.5

Can't figure out whats the issue here.

Thanks

```
 boolean isFiveBillOn = false, isTwentybillOn = false, isTenbillOn = false, isDollarOn = false, isQuartersOn = false, isDimesOn = false, isNicklesOn = false, isPenniesOn = false;

    //retrieve amount due
    String moneyd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount due");
    double amountd = Double.parseDouble(moneyd);

    String moneyr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter amount you would like to pay");
    double amountr = Double.parseDouble(moneyr);

    //calculate difference
    double difference = (amountr - amountd);

    //convert to pennies
    int balance = (int)(difference * 100);

    //twenty dollar bill
    int twentydollars = balance / 2000;
    balance = (balance % 2000);
    if (twentydollars > 0) {
        isTwentybillOn = true;
    }

    //ten dollar bill
    int tendollars = balance / 1000;
    balance = (balance % 1000);
    if (tendollars > 0) {
        isTenbillOn = true;
    }

    //five dollar bill
    int fivedollars = balance / 500;
    balance = (balance % 500);
    if (fivedollars > 0) {
        isFiveBillOn = true;
    }

    //dollar bill
    int dollars = balance / 100;
    balance = (balance % 100);
    if (dollars > 0) {
        isDollarOn = true;
    }

    //quartes
    int quarters = balance / 25;
    balance = (balance % 25);
    if (quarters > 0) {
        isQuartersOn = true;
    }

    //dimes
    int dimes = balance / 10;
    balance = (balance % 10);
    if (dimes > 0) {
        isDimesOn = true;
    }

    //nickles
    int nickles = balance / 5;
    balance = (balance % 5);
    if (nickles > 0){
        isNicklesOn = true;
    }

    //pennies
    int pennies = balance / 1;
    balance = (balance % 1);
    if (pennies > 0){
        isPenniesOn = true;
    }

    //checking for difference over 0
    if (difference < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount received can't be less than the amount owned");
    } else {
        // Returning Message
        } if (isTwentybillOn) {
                    System.out.println("Twenty dollar bill " + twentydollars);
        } if (isTenbillOn) {
                    System.out.println("Ten dollar bill: " + tendollars);
        } if (isDollarOn) {
                    System.out.println("One Dollar Bill: " + dollars);
        } if (isQuartersOn) {
                    System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarters);
        } if (isDimesOn) {
                    System.out.println("Dimes: " + dimes);
        } if (isNicklesOn) {
                    System.out.println("Nickles: " + nickles);
        } if (isPenniesOn) {
                    System.out.println("Pennies: " + pennies);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thanks! have a good day");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not use `double` to represent money. Use a `BigDecimal` or some other exact data type.

Comment: @Keppil - could you explain why?

Comment: because floating point numbers can not represent arbitrary real numbers. it is always just an approximation

Comment: Yep, in general you should never use float/double numbers to represent money (except perhaps if you're doing stock market analysis and precise to-the-penny results are not needed).  As to why, you've demonstrated that above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: @HotLicks, well I could vote to close for lack of research. I just think to find a duplicate question is easier to prove than the lack of research

Comment: @mardavi - So why didn't you vote to close?

Comment: @HotLicks, my fault, I misunderstood you. I cannot vote to close (not enough reputation), instead I flagged the question

Comment: @tfeichtinger Neither can `BigDecimal` objects.

Comment: @DavidWallace I did not claim they do (admittedly it does look so based on the previous comment). I was merely pointing out the reason for the issue/behavior posted by OP.

Comment: Hah, yeah, true.  Maybe I should post an answer, instead of a series of snide comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use a `double` or any other floating-point data type to represent money. The reason is that they can't represent all values exactly. For example, the following line:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.1));
```

prints

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

For a longer explanation why, see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

I suggest using [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

An alternative if you only want to use primitives is to use an `int` to store the currency value in cents instead, and divide by 100 when displaying the value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any other way? My professor hasn't been over BigDecimal yet. This project should not cover BigDecimal, any other suggestion.

Comment: @user3241911: I added an alternative solution using `int`.